# Confused about layers of FIX Protocol

Tags: protocols, network-protocols, fix-protocol

What is the difference between the FIX Application Layer, FIX Presentation Layer, and FIX Session Layer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FIX Session Layer is the part of the protocol responsible for the session framework. Things like authentication, connection control etc...

FIX Application Layer is the part responsible for actual application information. Things like order status, requests etc...

FIX Presentation Layer is the definition of how the protocol is actually commmunicated. Can be Tag=Value, Markup, Binary or others...